# Is there a template available for a smart contract which automatically sends tokens back when users send ETH or tokens to it?

Tags: tokens

Is there a template available for a smart contract which automatically sends tokens back when users send ETH or tokens to it?

Hello,

I am looking for code for a smart contract which automatically dispatches tokens to anyone that sends ETH or tokens to it. Has this been written yet? Maybe there is a template in GitHub somewhere?

If anyone knows where to find it, please post a link below.

Vesa

Answer (score 1):

Most crowdsales/ICOs work in that way. They have a fallback function which fires when someone just sends Ether to that address and the fallback function calls a buyToken function which internally handles the purchase of tokens and assignation to the internal balance for the user.

Here's one that comes to mind: https://github.com/merlox/pally/blob/master/contracts/Crowdsale.sol

```
/// @notice Fallback function to buy tokens
   function () payable {
      buyTokens();
   }
```

When someone sends ether to the contract it will fire buyTokens() that proceeds to calculate the corresponding amount of tokens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code [here](https://www.ethereum.org/token) with below steps.

1. Have your constructor payable in the coding so that you can pass some ether to it (which may be needed if you want to have trading facility like buy/sell)
2. Add a fallback function like below. This will be the used when one just sends Ether to your contract

   function () payable {
           buy();
       }
3. Deploy your contract (do not forget to pass constructor values), please send some ethers to it so that it can be used while selling also
4. Once the contract is deployed, send the tokens to the contract (by default the owner will receive the tokens, and thus the contract will not be able to return anything)

This is very basic thing that you should match your needs.